# Td .innerHTML not displaying when looping through children

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

When writing to a large table, looping through children to get a `td` and changing `innerHTML` does not display a value. However, adding

```
console.log(table.children[Math.floor(id/3)].children[id % 3].innerHtml);
```

at the end of `displayChar()` returns

[image: console]

```js
for ( var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
 displayChar('-', i);
}

function displayChar(char, id){
  var table = document.getElementById('table').tBodies[0];
  table.children[Math.floor(id/3)].children[id % 3].innerHtml = char;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a reason why the value of `innerHTML` is being edited but is not displayed in the document, whereas everything works when an id is used instead,  as shown below?

```js
for ( var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
 displayChar(i+'', i);
}

function displayChar(char, id){
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = char;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td id='0'>0</td>
    <td id='1'>0</td>
    <td id='2'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='3'>0</td>
    <td id='4'>0</td>
    <td id='5'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='6'>0</td>
    <td id='7'>0</td>
    <td id='8'>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive

It's innerHTML not innerHtml.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
for ( var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
 displayChar('-', i);
}

function displayChar(char, id){
  var table = document.getElementById('table').tBodies[0];
  table.children[Math.floor(id/3)].children[id % 3].innerHTML = char;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this could help, then this is simple code if you like:

```
for (var i = 0;i<9;i++) {
document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML = "-";
}
```

just don't set the ids for the tag `td` the method `document.getElementsByTagName()` will do it for all `tds`